# NativeScript iOS Metadata found but symbol not available at runtime

Tags: ios, nativescript, libsodium

I am trying to implement a custom plugin for NativeScript using `libsodium` (https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium). I have downloaded source files & complied to generate `libsodium.a` & header files. After that I put in my plugin following "https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/plugin-reference". It's generating typescript definition correctly but when I am trying to use in demo app like this:

```
console.dir(crypto_aead_aes256gcm_abytes())
```

But getting errors like this:

```
JavaScript error:
file:///app/main-view-model.js:8:49: JS ERROR ReferenceError: Metadata for "sodium.crypto_aead_aes256gcm_abytes" found but symbol not available at runtime.
(CoreFoundation) *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: ReferenceError: Metadata for "sodium.crypto_aead_aes256gcm_abytes" found but symbol not available at runtime.
```

Architectures:

```
lipo -info sodium.a    
Architectures in the fat file: sodium.a are: i386 armv7 armv7s x86_64 arm64
```

In where I am doing mistake? Please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Does your plugin contains Swift code? If yes you need to set the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` setting to YES in the plugin's xcconfig file to load the Swift runtime.

Comment: No, that's pure C library complied to iOS static library.

Comment: hmm, try to open an issue on Native Script Github you may get more help there. 
https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime